# Why Lord Shiva has a snake around his neck?

Tags: shiva-purana

I have never read about the story why Shiva has a serpant around his neck. Is it to stop the poison from entering his body ?

Comment: Snake refers to the poison of world. When God is not realized, the world appears to be very dangerous and full of poison. However for a Yogi, the world is no longer under the control of us, You become the Master of All Creation. Thus Lord Shiva, who sets an example for inspiring other Yogis, symbolically wears a snake around His neck, to show that He has conquered Illusions and is therefore the Master of the World.